# Retrieve output from c# execute

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I have created a C# console application .exe file and I'm calling this .exe file from powershell by passing some output arguments, I'm returning some result from exe. How I can get the output value from powershell.

Ex.
A =int1+int2

Return A:

In this above example I'm passing int1 and int2 from powershell.

Now I need to retrieve output Which is A from powershell.

Comment: Have you tried `Console.WriteLine(A);`

Comment: Please clarify your intent by directly updating your question: Do you simply want the console application to _output_ the result of `int1+int2`? If so, @ChadK's solution applies.

Comment: Strange scenario but Ok, maybe an exit code from the application?

Comment: I have written the output In console I'm able to see the log from powershell but I need to store the value into the variable.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. If you log it in the console like I said, then it's already stored in A

Answer (score 0):

Method return values in C# can only be referenced by other methods which invoke/call them.  It's not really possible to access return values outside of the application.

That being said, if you are returning A from your "main" method, then I *think* this would be the exit code for your application.  In that case, you could try referencing `$LASTEXITCODE` in PowerShell.  This isn't really the intended use for the application exit code, but I've seen the exit code being used before to pass data between applications.

If you only intend to use your application with PowerShell, then an alternative approach might be to convert it to a PowerShell cmdlet instead.

Comment: Or, as suggested above, write the value to console

Comment: This last exit code is giving me the output as 0.